# Setting name to unnamed index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have dataframe which look like this:

```
2000-01-03               4653.1
2000-01-10               4657.6
2000-01-17               4659.8
2000-01-24               4667.0
2000-01-31               4667.7
                        ...
2020-06-08              18248.9
2020-06-15              18329.3
2020-06-22              18429.5
2020-06-29              18424.6
2020-07-06              18522.1

[1071 rows x 1 columns]
```

I want to name the index column `Date` but i cannot `set_index` because it does not have a name. how can i set the name of index column when it does not have name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)

```
df = df.rename_axis('Date')
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the index can be set with its `name` property.

```py
df.index.name = 'Date'
```